# array of class in boo, unable to access properties

Tags: boo

So I've created a class in boo that has three properties, Name as string, required as bool, read as bool.

Then Im going to create a method(SetDefault) that goes through the array of this type and sets all required properties back to true, and read back to false.  Actually now that I think about it, Im not sure if it makes sense to have that as a method of the class.  Doesn't matter.

Bottom line is Im declaring an array of this class type i've created.

```
testvar as (MyAttribute) = array(MyAttribute,10)
```

Once I've declared my array of this class, Im unable to reference any of the properties by using...

```
testvar(0).Name
```

The error is "It is not possible to invoke an expression of type (MyAttribute)"

I assume to use an array because they're all going to be the same data type.  Is an array to correct type to use and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using square brackets for array member access i.e. `testvar[0].Name`.